# Proper way to use FMap in Coq 8.6?

Tags: dictionary, coq

I am trying to use a tree based map in Coq, specifically `Coq.FSets.FMapAVL`.

I found this 4 year old question: [Finite map example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489232/finite-map-example)

Looking at the standard lib documentation referenced in the comments, I see this note:

> NB: This file is here only for compatibility with earlier version of FSets and FMap. Please use Structures/Orders.v directly now.

What does this mean? When I google "Structures.v" or "Orders.v" I always end up at other documentation pages with related deprecation warnings.

What is the proper, non-deprecated way to use an FMap in Coq 8.6?

Comment: In case somebody needs sets, not maps: the stdlib [main page](https://coq.inria.fr/library/index.html) says: "**FSets**: Modular implementation of finite sets/maps using lists or efficient trees. For sets, please consider the more modern MSets".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `OrderedTypeEx` module is deprecated, we won't use `Nat_as_OT` defined in it.

There is `Nat_as_OT` in `OrdersEx` (just a synonym for `PeanoNat.Nat`), which is useful for our purposes.

Unfortunately, the following code

```
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrdersEx.
Module M := FMapAVL.Make Nat_as_OT.
```

won't work, because signatures `OrderedType.OrderedType` (currently used by `FMapAVL`) and `Orders.OrderedType` are not compatible.

However, the `OrdersAlt` module contains functors, which allow to build a module of one type from another. In this case, we are interested in `Backport_OT`. The following code shows how to use `FMapAVL.Make`, the rest of the code can be copied from the linked question:

```
From Coq Require Import
FSets.FMapAVL Structures.OrdersEx Structures.OrdersAlt.

Module backNat_as_OT := Backport_OT Nat_as_OT.
Module M := FMapAVL.Make backNat_as_OT.
```

The situation with `FMapAVL` was explained by Pierre Letouzey in [this Coq-Club post](http://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/CUmpsSYX/converting-orders-orderedtype-to-orderedtype-orderedtype#post4):

> the transition between old-style `OrderedType` and the new one isn't
>   finished yet (some work remain to be done on `FMaps` for instance),
>   and we cannot simply remove the old-style `OrderedType`.